# How to get sum of tickets as per priority from an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have the following array

```
{
agent_id:001,
priority:"High",
task_id:T1
},
{
agent_id:001,
priority:"High",
task_id:T1
},
{
agent_id:001,
priority:"Medium",
task_id:T1
}
{
agent_id:002,
priority:"High",
task_id:T1
}
```

I need to get an output of the above array as follows:

```
{agent_id:001,High_Count:2,Medium_Count:1},
{agent_id:002,High_Count:1,Medium_Count:0}
```

Here is my code:

for (let i = 0; i < dataModel.ticketList.length; i++) {
var priority = JSON.stringify(dataModel.ticketList[i].Priority);

```
        if (!map.has(priority)) 
        {
         map.set(priority, {
            Agent: dataModel.ticketList[i].Agent,
            Low: 1,
         });
        } 
        else 
        {
         map.get(priority).Low++;
        }
    }
```

const res = Array.from(map.values())
return res;

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Have you made an attempt? Can you share your attempt(s) with us so that we can hopefully teach you where you went wrong, and how to solve the problem? Please, take the [tour], then read both the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidance.

Comment: No I haven't attempt yet

Comment: Please do make that attempt and then add the code you tried, where you had a challenge with it so we might assist you in fixing it.

Comment: I have attempt and posted code

Answer (score 0):

Please use Array.reduce() function.

```js
const data = [{ agent_id:001, priority:"High", task_id:"T1" }, { agent_id:001, priority:"High", task_id:"T1" }, { agent_id:001, priority:"Medium", task_id:"T1" }, { agent_id:002, priority:"High", task_id:"T1" }];

const urgent = "Urgent";

let result = data.reduce((total, item) => {
    if(total.map(val => val.agent_id).includes(item.agent_id)) {
        const index = total.map(val => val.agent_id).indexOf(item.agent_id);
        if(total[index].hasOwnProperty(item.priority + "_Count"))
            total[index][item.priority + "_Count"] ++;
        else
            total[index][item.priority + "_Count"] = 1;
    } else {
        let obj = {agent_id: item.agent_id};
        let priorities = data.map(val => val.priority).filter((val, i, self) => self.indexOf(val) === i);
        if(!!urgent) priorities.push(urgent);
        priorities.forEach(val => {obj[val + "_Count"] = 0});
        obj[item.priority + "_Count"] = 1;
        total.push(obj);
    }
    return total;
},[]);

result = result.map(val => {
    const total = Object.keys(val).reduce((total, key) => key === 'agent_id' ? total : total + val[key], 0);
    return {...val, total: total};
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, please tell me if I need to add one extra priority i.e "Urgent" but there are no any record of such a priority into my array then what should I do ?

Comment: Where do you need to add one? data or result?

Comment: {
    "agent_id": 1,
    "High_Count": 2,
    "Medium_Count": 1
    "Urgent_Count": 0},
  {
    "agent_id": 2,
    "High_Count": 1,
    "Medium_Count": 0
    "Urgent_Count": 0}

Comment: I updated some parts. Please refer this.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot will go through it.

Comment: Actually there might be sometime only High and low are present in to array, or some time only high present and sometime only urgent present then corresponding priorities must set 0

Comment: Yes, of course. It implemented in the code.

Comment: I hope your work is going well. vote??? :)

Comment: Hello is there any scope if I need to add one more column {
    "agent_id": 1,
    "High_Count": 2,
    "Medium_Count": 1,
    "Urgent_Count": 0
     "Total" : 3},
  {
    "agent_id": 2,
    "High_Count": 1,
    "Medium_Count": 0,
    "Urgent_Count": 0
     "Total": 1}

Comment: Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this:

```js
const data = [
  { agent_id: 001, priority: "High", task_id: "T1" },
  { agent_id: 001, priority: "High", task_id: "T1" },
  { agent_id: 001, priority: "Medium", task_id: "T1" },
  { agent_id: 002, priority: "High", task_id: "T1" },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex((x) => x.agent_id === cur.agent_id);

  if (~index) {
    const value = acc[index][`${cur.priority}_Count`] || 0;
    acc.splice(index, 1, {
      ...acc[index],
      [`${cur.priority}_Count`]: value + 1,
    });
  } else {
    acc.push({ agent_id: cur.agent_id, [`${cur.priority}_Count`]: 1 });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much but please tell me what logic i need to implement if value is only present for High_count and for Medium_count there are no data then I need to show 0 for Medium_count like{
    "agent_id": 1,
    "High_Count": 2,
    "Medium_Count": 1
  },
  {
    "agent_id": 2,
    "High_Count": 1,
  Medium_count: 0}